# Micronaut with kafka fails to retrieve metadata on first attempts

Tags: docker, groovy, apache-kafka, micronaut

I'm trying to send messages from a Micronaut 3.6.3 application to Kafka deployed with docker-compose. On first attempt I receive a warning like this:

> [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with
> correlation id 1 : {accountRegistered=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

For the following messages, the problem disappear but my requirement is to not lost any about account registration.

My docker compose configuration:

```
services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:3.2'
    hostname: 'kafka'
    environment:
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://kafka:29092, OUTSIDE://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INSIDE'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://:29092, OUTSIDE://:9092'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INSIDE:PLAINTEXT, OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    depends_on:
      - 'zookeeper'
  #TODO: Can be removed with the future versions of Kafka (using KRaft)
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3.8'
    hostname: 'zookeeper'
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: 'yes'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
```

From the application I use 'localhost:9092' to connect.

My consumer code:

```
@KafkaListener(offsetReset = OffsetReset.EARLIEST)
class AccountReferenceUpdaterEventConsumer {

    @Inject
    AccountReferenceEntityRepository accountReferenceEntityRepository

    @Topic('accountRegistered')
    void receive(@MessageBody AccountRegisteredEvent event) {

        def account = event.source
        accountReferenceEntityRepository.findById(account.id)
                .ifPresentOrElse(
                        accountReference -> log.warn('Account {} already registered', account.id),
                        () -> {

                            def accountReference = new AccountReferenceEntity(
                                    accountId: account.id,
                                    username: account.username
                            )
                            accountReferenceEntityRepository.save(accountReference)
                        }
                )
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: 'localhost:9092'
```

Comment: What happens when you restart the containers with `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://:29092, OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092`

Comment: Also, not clear what you mean by "not lost any about account registration.". A producer can be configured with retires, and has nothing to do with "accounts"

Comment: Thanks for reply. Using 0.0.0.0 it's the same. To be more specific, when I create a new user account, I add an event about the new user registration to a topic named "accountRegistered". With this problem, the first account registered do send nothing so, the current state is inconsistent, for this reason i need to not lost these messages. :-)

Comment: Is it possible that topic didn't exist yet? The first record you send will automatically create that topic, and print some errors such as "leader not found"

Comment: I think that micronaut create it on first access.

Comment: After some investigation, Micronaut create a topic and add a message inside but, the consumers on the other side, found no message to retrieve.

Comment: I have updated the question with consumer code and properties

Comment: Where are you setting `group.id` for the consumer?

Comment: From the micronaut docs, is defaulted to "micronaut.application.name"

Comment: Your code looks fine, overall, but I haven't used Micronaut. You can debug the consumer group itself using `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` command to see if there is any lag in the topic for the consumer to read data.

Comment: I have resolved adding a custom group.id to the consumer. IMHO seems that with the default, message is already consumed from another consumer in the same group but I do not have others. Thanks for you support, @OneCricketeer :-)